# Lubuntu Netbook shows root partition full

Tags: hard-drive, lubuntu, ubuntu-netbook, root

I've been using Lubuntu Netbook for quite a few days (on Asus EeePC 1015PX), but recently I encountered a problem. I could not copy files to my root partition. I looked for the files that were eating up space, found some log files of huge size and deleted them.

It worked fine for few days, but now it again shows the root partition full.

Output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6        22G   22G     0 100% /
udev            489M   39M  451M   8% /dev
tmpfs           199M  904K  198M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            496M  104K  496M   1% /run/shm
```

Output of `sudo du -hcs $(ls) 2> /dev/null`:

```
8.5M    bin
27M boot
4.0K    cdrom
39M dev
18M etc
149M    home
0   initrd.img
180M    lib
16K lost+found
4.0K    media
4.0K    mnt
4.0K    opt
2.3M    root
1008K   run
8.8M    sbin
4.0K    selinux
4.0K    srv
0   sys
60K tmp
4.2G    usr
399M    var
0   vmlinuz
5.1G    total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolved after I restarted my computer.